# Unable to find SPUCWorkerProcess.exe while debugging Sandbox Solution

Tags: event-receivers, deployment, sandbox-solution, form-library

I am creating Sandbox solution to attach Event Receiver to Form Library.I want to debug the solution but it is giving me error

> Unable to attach process 'SPUCWorkerProcess.exe' is not running on 'ServerName'

I have checked

1. SharePoint User Code Host service running in services
2. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service is running in Central Admin
3. In Central Administration -> Farm Management -< Manage User Soltuion -> Selected option All sandboxed code runs on the same machine as a request.

but still same issue exists